# Combine power from power supply and LiPo battery

Tags: power, lipo

I am working on a hybrid electric power system project which currently has a 300W power supply and a 2S-910mAh LiPo battery. I would like for both sources to provide power if the load demand exceeds 300W.

I was wondering if there was any method for me to safely 'combine' the power output of the two sources.

Edit: to clarify the components used currently are not sized for any actual operations but to understand and verify power combination. Ideally the power supply wattage should be in similar range as the battery being used.

Comment: If the 300W power supply limits current such that the output voltage decreases when a current limit is hit (rather than shutting off the output, or going into a hiccup mode). You can parallel the two (probably with a diode on the battery) so that the power supply provides all of the power until the current limit kicks in and drops the voltage to that of the battery. I'm actually doing something similar right now, but the battery first goes through a boost stage to get a consistent voltage.

Comment: If a main power source is 300W power supply, then adjust battery to deliver energy effectively is not a easy thing. The battery voltage changes so there is demand to add converter to battery with special current regulation loop sensing the 300W supply current also. If effectivnes does not matter, there is a chance to add active serial resistance to battery using transistors. However, if both sources are low serial resistance and you want to they work effectively keeping Rs low it´s a madness.

Comment: Btw, adding two poor battery to 300W power supply is a pointless unless the parallelism is used short time only.

Comment: Why not use a bigger battery? The additional amount of energy you will get from the 2S-910mAh LiPo battery is not much. It is rated a little over 5 watts assuming they are in series.  Knowing the voltages involved would be a big help.

Comment: Your component sizes make no sense to me.  2S=~8V.  300W/8V=37.5A, and even high end high current 18650 cells seem to be only rated for 35A. The other thing is .9Ah will only run 37.5A for 1 minute 26s, and this doesn't take into account that you have to derate(decrease) the Ah rating if you are drawing more than the rated test current.  That would be a really short runtime even by novelty flashlight or high performance remote controlled vehicle standards, which are the shortest acceptable battery life applications I can think of.

Comment: thanks for the comments, to add on, current I'm testing to find if the power power combination could be done. the components and values are currently scaled down. The power supply mentioned could be limited by both voltage and current. So if I reduce the power output to a similar wattage range as the battery, I would have to use like a dc-dc converter to keep the battery voltage stable?